# Google Sheets sharing setting, "Specific people can access" but can't see each other

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-sharing

For Google sheets sharing setting, I have it on "Specific people can access", but the people can see who has access to that sheet. Is there anyway to make the setting so that the specific people can't see who else has access to that sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
For security reasons Google will always show the people a sheet is shared with.
Your only other alternative would be to set it to public, but that would negate the option of "Specific people can access".

Comment: I keep coming back to this question... what are the "security reasons" Google is concerned with? why can't people just view? But I can control who can view? I think this feature would be uber useful. There is sensitive information you can't share with the whole public, but you don't want people to know who else sees the info.

Comment: What is the source of "for security reasons...". Anyway, rather than "security" I think that this is about a privacy concern rather than about security. (By the way, there are other alternatives, I posted one of them on my answer)

Comment: @Rubén I am afraid I cannot recall the exact source anymore. It was my mistake to not note it down on the answer. I remember though it was from an official google site. I was struck as well by their use of such a strong language.

Comment: @marikamitsos No big problem, maybe that source isn't available anymore specially because nowadays Google is being observed very closely by security and privacy specialists. i.e. they closed G+ and are making changes to https://myaccount.google.com, Google Groups, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I already mentioned this on a recent question [When sharing folders on Google Drive do users know who else the folder is shared with](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/129720/88163)

> Users that are explictely included on the sharing settings could see
>   who else has access to the file. To prevent this, create a Google
>   Group, add the collaborators (editors/viewers) to that group then
>   share the folder with the group.
>
> In order to make this work, the group settings should not allow
>   members to see the members list.
>
> Related
>
> - [Sharing Google Drive file using groups](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/116285/88163)