# Sharing Google Drive file using groups

Tags: google-drive, google-groups, google-workspace-for-business, file-sharing

I am using G Suite and I had a plan to organize all my employees into groups. Rather than sharing files individually with everyone, I want to share it with a group, so that all the employees present in the group can have similar access.
My question is what if I add a new member to the group, would he have access to all the files that was shared prior to him joining the group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you add a new member to a group used to share files in Google Drive, the new member will be able to access the files shared with the group previously.

From [Use groups to share content](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167101?hl=en)

> If you later add new members to the group, they'll be able to access the document only via the document's URL. To make the document appear in the Shared with Me view of a new member's Google Drive, you must reshare the document with the group or share the document with the new member individually.

Comment: So, if I add an employee to a group, his drive would already be populated with the files that I shared with the group he is in?

Comment: Noup. He will be able to access the files shared with the group but in order to get them into his drive he will have to add them to his drive.

Comment: So, the group files could be found under the "shared under me" folder. He would have to drag the files from that folder to his drive. Am I on right track?

Comment: @goodfellas95 I edited my answer. Please check it out. By the other hand, if you have G Suite accounts, take a look to Team Drives.

Comment: In order to use team drives, I have to pay for it. I was wondering if the basic drive covers my use case or not, hence the question

Comment: @goodfellas95 well, you now know how the use of groups to share files works, you have to decide if you will reshare the documents or find another way to let the new members learn which files they have access to.