# When sharing folders on Google Drive do users know who else the folder is shared with?

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-sharing

I want to invite various people to a shared Google Drive folder but do not want each of the users (except myself) to see the names of the other users with which the folder has been shared.

Comment: **Possible duplicate**. Please see the answer here: [Google Sheets sharing setting, “Specific people can access” but can't see each other](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/92392)

Answer (score 2):

Users that are explictely included on the sharing settings could see who else has access to the file. To prevent this, create a Google Group, add the collaborators (editors/viewers) to that group then share the folder with the group.

In order to make this work, the group settings should not allow members to see the members list.

Related

- [Sharing Google Drive file using groups](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/116285/88163)

Comment: Though I find Google Groups quite cumbersome I think it is a great workaround.

Comment: It does not seem that sharing files with a group is available anymore.

Comment: @GuillermoBCN Please provide more details or post a new question. Also, please note that this question is closed as a duplicate of another question. I have posted an answer to that question, including a link to the corresponding help article. Please review the linked article thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

You can share your folder by link (eg. not adding users to the list) in which case all users are treated as "Anonymous" to each other (even to you - which is the only possible downside).

To answer the question in the title - only you and people you added to the sharing list are able to see each other's names. Everyone else is just Anonymous.